# hyberlink in gridview not change the color

Tags: asp.net, gridview, colors

`ASP.Net` `+C#`
I have a **web page** and a `GridView` in it 
in my code some where i need to change the color of data it display
something like :

```
GridView1.Rows[y].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 204, 0);
```

the problem is:
i have a **hyberlike in some cells** of the `GridView` and when i change the color the change affects only the text in cells with no hyberlinks and the hyberlinks still blue.
thanks in advance

Comment: As a tip use a tool like Firebug to determine where the hyperlink color comes from. May be there is some global style which overrides ForeColor property value.

Answer (score 2):

put 
color :inherit;
in css class